# Get the values of a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary as the following.

```
myTodo= {          
                'taskid': '10',
                'taskstatus': 'in progress',

                'Kitchen': 
                {                    
                    'Stove':{
                                'LED1':
                                {
                                'taskid': '11',
                                'taskstatus':'running'
                                },

                                'LED2':
                                {
                                    'taskid': '12',
                                    'taskstatus':'off',
                                    'LEDSub':
                                    { 
                                       'taskid': '13',
                                       'taskstatus':'stable',
                                       'LEDSub2':
                                        {
                                           'taskid': '14',
                                           'taskstatus':'burnt'
                                        }
                                    }
                                },

                                'LED3':
                                {
                                'taskid': '15',
                                'taskstatus':'new'
                                } 
                           },
                  //other nested layers
               }
```

I have a python method which returns me the route based on keys to get to a 'value'. 
The method is shown below.

```
 def route(myTodo, id):
        q = list()
        q.append((list(), myTodo))
        while q:
            this_key_chain, this_v = reverse_linked_q.pop()
            # finish search if found the id 
            if this_v == id:
                return this_key_chain
            # not found. keep searching        
            try:
                items = this_v.items()
            except AttributeError:
                continue
            for k, v in items:
                q.append((this_key_chain + [k], v))
        raise KeyError
```

This method returns me the route in terms of the keys. So if I `route(myTodo, "11")`, it will return me the list, keyroute=["Kitchen", "Stove", "LED1", "taskid"].

Then I delete the "taskid" from the keyroute list and send that list to the following method.

```
    def createOutputDic(keyroute, myTodo):
        for k in keyroute:
            myTodo = myTodo.get(k)
        return j
```

For `route(myTodo, "11")`, the output from the `createOutputDic(keyroute,myTodo)` is

```
{ 
 'taskid': '11',
 'taskstatus':'running'
}
```

The issue comes when I make the call as `route(myTodo, "12")`. I expect to get

```
{ 'taskid': '12',
  'taskstatus':'off'
}
```

but the result is

```
{ 
  'taskid': '12',
  'taskstatus':'off',
  'LEDSub':
   { 
     'taskid': '13',
     'taskstatus':'stable',
   'LEDSub2':
   {
     'taskid': '14',
     'taskstatus':'burnt'
   }
}
```

I want to just get

```
{ 'taskid': '12',
  'taskstatus':'off'
}
```

but I dont get why the current route(..) method is not able to do it. 
**The dictionary could be deeply nested and I want to have a generic method.**
Can someone please help me or guide me on a better way to resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion with a [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/):

```
def get_data(d, val):
  if any(c == val for c in d.values()):
     yield {i:d.get(i) for i in ['taskid', 'taskstatus']}
  else:
     for i in d.values():
        if isinstance(i, dict):
           yield from get_data(i, val)

myTodo = {'taskid': '10', 'taskstatus': 'in progress', 'Kitchen': {'Stove': {'LED1': {'taskid': '11', 'taskstatus': 'running'}, 'LED2': {'taskid': '12', 'taskstatus': 'off', 'LEDSub': {'taskid': '13', 'taskstatus': 'stable', 'LEDSub2': {'taskid': '14', 'taskstatus': 'burnt'}}}, 'LED3': {'taskid': '15', 'taskstatus': 'new'}}}}
result = list(get_data(myTodo, '12'))
print(result if not result else result[0])
```

Output:

```
{'taskid': '12', 'taskstatus': 'off'}
```

To format the output a dictionary is created with the same keys contained in the desired output. The `yield` statements create a generator object that points to other objects in memory, "generated" on the fly. A generator-based solution is a bit cleaner than using `return`, as the latter would require the creation of a list outside the second `for` loop to which the returned results from each `get_data` call can be appended to. Ultimately, it is cleaner to simply use `yield` at each `get_data` call.

Comment: I am not sure what is a generator and I am a bit confused with the "yield". May you please elaborate how the output will look with your suggest solution. I would really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: For instance, if I put an id such as 1000, I get the error IndexError: list index out of range. I used a try except like this,                            
        ```try:
               mylist = list(get_data(d, id_type))[0]

Comment: @LauraSmith That is because a generator object be iterated over (either by calling `list` or looping over it). If the value is not found in `myTodo`, an empty list will be returned, because the base case:`yield {i:d.get(i) for i in ['taskid', 'taskstatus']}` was never executed. Please see my recent edit, as I added a simple change to reflect this possibility.